# Downsides with a single NextJS catch-all route at the root level, for all CMS pages?

Tags: next.js, content-management-system, nextjs-dynamic-routing

We are evaluating **NextJS** for an upcoming total rewrite of our frontend, and overall it looks quite promising. But the file centric or url-path-sentric routing gives us some headache. Our URLs are handled by the CMS.

Here are some example paths:

```
/
/frimp/
/frimp/fromp/
/blunk-joins-blirp_123.html
/grob/end-of-the-year-bopster-party_456.html
/grob/blint/golle-world-record_789.html
/gnek/klip/rul/tunient?hoff=himp&kroo=45
```

All of these represent content in the CMS, and the content can be of various types, like news articles, events, videos etc. **The path gives us no information of what type of content it is.** To know that, we have to query the CMS. And different types of content can be rendered in very different ways. ***The way the CMS controls the URLs is set in stone, and can't be changed in any way.*** This means that I can't put all CMS pages under a common path (like "/cms/").

As far as I understand it, it should be possible to configure NextJS to handle all this, by simply defining a single **catch-all route directly in the root**, that handles all CMS-related URLs, and chooses what components to render based on the data from the CMS. I'm assuming that NextJS knows if a request is for it's own content (css, js, icons etc) even thought they also might reside at the root level of the website, and only asks the catch-all route to handle all other requests.

Now, my questions:

- Can someone here confirm or refute that what we want to do is possible in NextJS, without "hacking" it beyond reason? And that we won't go against some "principle" of NextJS.
- If we do this, are there some major downsides with this aproach? Will it make Server Side Rendering or Client Side Rendering more difficult, for example? (We want to have both.)